# Do we need kafka connection pool from client?

Tags: apache-kafka, connection-pooling

I have a REST webservice with traffic about 1 mil requests per day. In that REST service, for each request, we send message to remote kafka topic. Do I have to set up Kafka connection pool to improve the performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't need to keep the Kafka connection pooling. Kafka clients keep the connections with the Kafka cluster and it will manage all the connections. As long as you have enough partitions configured for the Kafka topic, it should be alright.

Comment: Consumer client pool can be useful for multi threading. Producers or AdminClient don't need it